# Running Firebase functions code on Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I'm using Firebase functions written in TypeScript and want to try to run the code with the least possible changes on Cloud Run. The best solution I've found so far is to wrap the Firebase functions in a Docker container using [buildpacks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/google-cloud-now-supports-buildpacks) and then deploy it to Cloud Run. They support Google Cloud Functions, so in theory, it should be possible.

I tried to follow the demo [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suhCr5W_bFc) but had no luck. After generating the buildpack, it errors with `command not found: firebase`, which comes from the start script (`firebase serve --only functions`). I tried changing it to `npx firebase...`, but I still get the same error.

Any suggestions on fixing this?

Build command: `pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder buildpack-my-functions`
Stacktrace:

```
latest: Pulling from buildpacks/builder
Digest: sha256:5148ca194b65b8c7e771e878353e0c204d56a7c53947dcb5800bcc6507b51be1
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:latest
v1: Pulling from buildpacks/gcp/run
Digest: sha256:ae69bbad23be8d56c4cedba0aaaa2a8f298bbc00abcab5922b40ca0014f00718
Status: Image is up to date for gcr.io/buildpacks/gcp/run:v1
0.9.3: Pulling from buildpacksio/lifecycle
Digest: sha256:bc253af2edf1577717618cb3a95f0f16bb18fc9e804efbcc1b85f657d931a757
Status: Image is up to date for buildpacksio/lifecycle:0.9.3
===> DETECTING
[detector] 3 of 5 buildpacks participating
[detector] google.nodejs.runtime 0.9.2
[detector] google.nodejs.npm     0.9.0
[detector] google.utils.label    0.0.1
===> ANALYZING
[analyzer] Restoring metadata for "google.nodejs.runtime:node" from app image
[analyzer] Restoring metadata for "google.nodejs.npm:npm" from cache
===> RESTORING
[restorer] Restoring data for "google.nodejs.runtime:node" from cache
[restorer] Restoring data for "google.nodejs.npm:npm" from cache
===> BUILDING
[builder] === Node.js - Runtime (google.nodejs.runtime@0.9.2) ===
[builder] Resolving Node.js version based on semver "10"
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] Running "curl --fail --show-error --silent --location --get --data-urlencode range=10 http://semver.io/node/resolve"
[builder] 10.23.2Done "curl --fail --show-error --silent --location --get --data-ur..." (1.163948619s)
[builder] Using resolved runtime version from package.json: 10.23.2
[builder] Runtime cache hit, skipping installation.
[builder] === Node.js - NPM (google.nodejs.npm@0.9.0) ===
[builder] Installing application dependencies.
[builder] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[builder] Running "npm install --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)"


... other builder logs ...


[builder] Done "npm install --quiet (NODE_ENV=production)" (51.751284576s)
[builder] === Utils - Label Image (google.utils.label@0.0.1) ===
===> EXPORTING
[exporter] Reusing layer 'google.nodejs.runtime:node'
[exporter] Reusing layer 'google.nodejs.npm:env'
[exporter] Adding 1/1 app layer(s)
[exporter] Reusing layer 'launcher'
[exporter] Reusing layer 'config'
[exporter] Reusing layer 'process-types'
[exporter] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.lifecycle.metadata'
[exporter] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.build.metadata'
[exporter] Adding label 'io.buildpacks.project.metadata'
[exporter] Setting default process type 'web'
[exporter] *** Images (74d17285fd66):
[exporter]       buildpack-my-functions
[exporter] Reusing cache layer 'google.nodejs.runtime:node'
[exporter] Reusing cache layer 'google.nodejs.npm:npm'
Successfully built image buildpack-my-functions
```

Comment: Can you share the buildpack log trace? It's maybe because Buildpack doesn't detect correctly your code type and format, that ir uses a wrong base image and thus you have this issue.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Your buildpack process detect code with nodejs. And use a Node JS runtime image to run your code. It works well!!

But not for your use case. you need to customize the runtime image to use an image with firebase installed on it. For this, you can use the parameter `--run-image` and have a command like this

```
pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder --run-image=<Firebase image>  buildpack-my-functions
```

I'm not a user of firebase, and I looked for runtime image of firebase and I found nothing except description to [how to build yourselves your runtime image](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase).

Buildpack is great, the principle is here, but not so easy to use (for firebase)...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: I managed to build the Firebase image and upload it to Cloud Build. Now trying to figure out how to use it with BuildPack. I'm not sure how to use it because it's a remote image.

Comment: Made a local build by following https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-debug-locally, but now I'm up against another error: `run-image stack id '' does not match builder stack 'google'`